# Error with Pandas: reading a function from another python script

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, module

I have a python script called `rateQualityMainTL.py` that has inside it a function also called `rateQualityMainTL`

The script that has the body of function show something similar to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

def rateQualityMainTL (x,y,z)
   Holds=pd.DataFrame(data)
   body of function
   return Newdataframe
```

I created another python script in order to call the function rateQualityMainTL. Following my reading on internet  I did

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    #-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
    import sys
    import numpy
    import os
    import rateQualityMainTL
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import DataFrame
    rateQualityMainTL.rateQualityMainTL(x,y,z)
```

when I run the code I get a error saying

```
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

I did define pandas so why do i get this error? is this related to the path? 
Thank you

Comment: Make sure new python script called from same path.

Comment: they both saved under the same location

Comment: does the script with the function rateQualityMainTL need to be defined in a particular manner before being "module"  the syntax is correct but it is not recognizing the module

Comment: Can you share the sample code of both function definition and invoking script

Comment: i have edited the question. see if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Python where to find modules on disk, When you import a package python looks for that package in the default python directories(Ex: anaconda folder etc.) and the working directory. If there is another directory then You need to add the path of the package in your system paths.you can add it like below:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path')
```

Comment: If the answer helped you, Please care to upvote and accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: where do i add this line of code? in the script that has the function or in the calling script? when i add it in the calling script i get a new error  `name 'pd' is not defined`    i am not sure why i get this error because i already added `import pandas as pd`

Comment: You need to add this piece of code in the calling script. You are just telling python where to look for packages when you import a package.

You can check all the paths that Python is currently searching for using 'sys.path',

Comment: as mentioned i did add `import pandas as pd` in the calling script but i still get the same error

Comment: You need to 'import pandas as pd' inside the function script as well. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: i added the import pandas inside the function but it did not work either...i now run the calling script from mobaxterm and it works fine  however when i run the calling script from the command line i still get the error i mentioned above